# how to send email for mac and pc compatible in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

i needed to send out an email when the user clicks on a button on a HTML page. The email has a heading, a text and a hyperlinked image in the body. At the moment I have been using an '.oft' file saved from a HTML template but this means that it is only PC supported and not Mac. I needed to make it universally possible. what other way would i be able to do this?

the '.oft' is attached to the 'email.png' file

code for the html site itself:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>TEST SITE</title>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /> 
    <meta name="Keywords" content="" /> 
    <meta name="Description" content="" /> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="help/css/reset.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="help/css/style.css" />

  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascript/lightbox/themes/default/jquery.lightbox.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/lightbox/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('.lightbox').lightbox();
    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.lightbox("video/reel-hi.html?lightbox[iframe]=true&lightbox[width]=530&lightbox[height]=430");

  });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content-in">
            <div id="content-container">
                <a href="video/reel-hi.html?lightbox[iframe]=true&lightbox[width]=530&lightbox[height]=430" class="lightbox" alt="Thank you for your patience!"><img src="bg.jpg" /></a><br />
                    <a href="email.oft"><img src="email.png" border="0" /></a>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, read this sites' help section: this is not a human-driven HTML-linter. Tag-spraying (what's with the PHP tag?) is frowned upon. There are plenty of tools/email designers out on the web. They are free, and quite comprehensive. One thing though: JS in email messages? I don't think that's even close to a half-decent idea

Comment: Thanks Elias for the comment, the above code is for the main page, the .oft is attached to a single button 'email.png'. So i just needed guidance on what type of file i can use to attached to the same button that will work on mac and PC.

Comment: A png works on all systems: it's an open format. Most CSS sprites are png's, for example. But if you don't want everything to be an image, google OFT to HTML